# How can I confirm that an Outlook email chain which was forwarded to me is genuine?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

In this scenario, all the email activity was done with Outlook clients and MS Exchange.

I got an mail from B that includes a forwarded chain which suggests that B was authorised by C to take an action. B wants me to trust this chain as proof he was acting on something with approval. However, I am sceptical and C is adamant that he never sent B the mail that has been forwarded.

In C’s email account there is no trace of a request from B, no trace of a reply from C, and no trace of any deletion. While that is not proof, there is no reason whatsoever why C needs to conceal this. I suspect that B has copied a previous approval request email for a similar event, but edited the date and time it was sent to C, hoping to cover this latest event. I fear he has also created a fake reply from C and then forwarded this all to me as “proof”.

Can the email headers show that the alleged “ask-reply” chain did not really happen at the time and date that B has tried to represent? Is there any other technical indicator that will show the real provenance of B’s forwarded email chain?

Comment: In short: you can not.

Comment: If the communication between B and C used DKIM, you could find the unique signatures that B reused or prove that the messages from C are invalid due to wrong signature. Otherwise you can't prove anything like @MátéJuhász says.

Answer (score 0):

Email headers doesn't contain information about preceding mails,  so you can't prove anything.

In the future the best way is to change the process: B should always copy C when refers to his approval,  or even better: C should send his approval directly to you (keeping B in copy)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if the email was simply forwarded, there is now way from the email itself that you can verify the chain. The headers (`File -> Properties -> Internet Headers`) only apply to that email.

If the email was forwarded as an attachment, then you could inspect the headers of each individual email.

You need a system outside of the email client itself to verify the chain. Best would be an email archiving solution (such as [Barracuda](https://www.barracuda.com/products/messagearchiver)) that records all email in a read-only format.

Failing that, you should ask the Exchange administrators. You don't specify the version of Exchange used, so here are two options

- MS Exchange 2010: Within the `Exchange Management Console` there is an option for `Toolbox`. In the toolbox is a tool called `Tracking Log Explorer`. You can use this tool to search for messages at a finer granularity, and without selecting specific mailboxes, but based on email addresses, etc. [as stated by HostBits](https://serverfault.com/a/540256/249125).
- MS Exchange Online: Use the `Get-MessageTrackingLog` PowerShell command as documented [here](http://techgenix.com/retrieve-message-tracking-logs-exchange-online-and-eop/) & [here](https://practical365.com/exchange-server/searching-message-tracking-logs-by-sender-or-recipient-email-address/).